# Opening a new Tabbed Window in Chrome with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that involves opening a new tabbed window in certain situations. I have tried utilizing:

```
window.open(url, "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes")
```

However, in this situation it simply opens a new window with no possibilities of creating new tabs in said window. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Use [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) in the browser_action script or background script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toolbar is not supported for chrome. it works for firefox and explorer.

```
 window.open("https://www.google.com.tr", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes")
```